# How to develop win form application for the system with the resolution of 1080*1920

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to develop a windows form application where the destination system is having screen resolution of 1080x1920. but my system is not accepting that resolution . even i cant set my winform size to 1080x1920.
can anybody help me out to solve this problem

Comment: ..is this a screen that is rotated vertically?  The standard HD size is 1920x1080, so unless you are designing this form for a vertical (portrait) screen, you may have your x and y backwards

Comment: this screen is rotated.

Comment: I suggest a method. In form designer code create an if code which if true your buttons and other form staff are created based on percentage calculation

Comment: how can i design it.?

Comment: Explain what “my system is not accepting that resolution” means.

Comment: I suspect that the screen being rotated is not known by the application, so you're putting in the wrong numbers. Generally it's better to read from environment configuration to get values rather than making assumptions and hard coding numbers. I gave you an answer which does not operate on such assumptions. However, if it is known to the application the environment configuration should still be correct. Please try it and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. This is the Load event for the form (you can generate this by double clicking the form in the designer). In this event we check the current dimensions of the screen containing the form. Then we set the form size to match. We also move the form's position to 0, 0 so it doesn't clip off the screen.

```
    //the name of this function will be different for you.
    //generate this function by double clicking the form in designer.
    //the code inside the function is what you're interested in.
    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle screenSize = Screen.GetBounds(this); //find out the current screen size
        this.Top = 0; //move the form to top
        this.Left = 0; //move the form to left
        this.Width = screenSize.Width; //set form width to screen width
        this.Height = screenSize.Height; //set form height to screen height
    }
```

EDIT: Also, why not just maximize?

```
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```